# How to read external variables

Tags: string, go, var

I am trying to read a variable sent as an external parameter by `--configFile=""`, but I always get an error not found, even if I pass the absolute path

**Vars:**

```
var (
    c                          Config
    conf                       = c.getConf()
    app                        = kingpin.New("exporter", "Exporter for Prometheus.")
    configFile                 = app.Flag("configFile", "Configuration file destination (/etc/exporter/config.yaml)").Default("/etc/exporter/config.yaml").String()
)
```

**Config:**

```
func (c *Config) getConf() *Config {

    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(string(*configFile))
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("yamlFile.Get err   #%v ", err)
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
    }
    return c
}
```

**Command/Output:**

```
server:/etc/exporter # ./exporter --configFile="/etc/exporter/config.yaml"
ERRO[0000] yamlFile.Get err   #open : no such file or directory
```

**ls -ltr:**

```
total 14152
-rw------- 1 root root     1334 Sep 25 20:47 config.yaml
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 14466568 Sep 25 22:03 exporter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace code here https://github.com/rafal-szypulka/itm_exporter/blob/master/main.go#L51

with:

```golang
conf *Config
```

Replace code here https://github.com/rafal-szypulka/itm_exporter/blob/master/main.go#L354

with:

```golang
p := kingpin.MustParse(app.Parse(os.Args[1:]))
conf = c.getConf()
switch p {
```

Comment: but when I add static variable, example: `yaml File, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/etc/exporter/config.yaml")`. The script execute with succesfully!

Comment: Your problem is that kingpin isn't parsing. You have to call `kingpin.MustParse`.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: I think if you look at the source code, you can understand better https://github.com/rafal-szypulka/itm_exporter

Comment: Yeah, they call MustParse here: https://github.com/rafal-szypulka/itm_exporter/blob/master/main.go#L354. Also the config.yaml file is hardcoded so they don't have to worry about the order of MustParse.

Comment: but how to make config.yaml received by `--configFile`?

Comment: Perhaps like: `p := kingpin.MustParse(app.Parse(os.Args[1:])); conf = getConf(); switch p { // ...` but it's kind of ugly.

Comment: No problem, could you provide an excerpt in the answer? I'm a beginner in GO

Comment: Added instructions.

Comment: Simply excellent, thank you, what do you recommend for GO study material?

Comment: Probably https://www.golang-book.com/, but I haven't read them.